# Are dualities necessarily quantum mechanical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, duality

What happens to dualities in a certain limit where quantum mechanics is turned off?
Like sending $\hbar/S$ $\rightarrow0$ where $S$ is the action of each side of the duality.
Does the duality have a classical remnant no matter how ugly it might be?
If not, does it mean that duality is necessarily a ***quantum*** phenomenon?

Comment: How about [EM duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montonen%E2%80%93Olive_duality)?

Comment: Also relevant is the fluid/gravity correspondence, eg: https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5780, https://www.ias.edu/ideas/2014/minwalla-dynamics

Comment: Well in this case the multiplication of magnetic and electric charge is proportional to $\hbar$ which means it's still quantum mechanics manifesting there! At least this is how I see it. Maye wrong. @Qmechanic

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. so you mean that dualities that are merely classical exist?
What about the classical limit of quantum mechanical dualitis?

Comment: @BastamTajik Well, the classical duality between fluid/gravity was motivated by the AdS/CFT correspondence, which is a quantum duality. I don't know enough about the details to say whether or not the fluid/gravity gravity correspondence is literally a classical limit of the AdS/CFT correspondence, but I think it's relevant since it is a surprising connection between two different classical theories which was discovered by studying a quantum duality.

Comment: $S/\hbar \to 0$ is the classical limit, not a duality; the classical Harmonic oscillator has a $(k,m) \to (1/m,1/k)$ duality.

Comment: @bolbteppa I guess you just misunderstood me.
I'm concerned about the classical limits of quantum mechanical dualities. :)

Comment: Let's say some like the simple S duality between the Massive Thirring model and the Sine-Gordon Model both in D=1+1. But honestly, I was more curious about a case like AdS/CFT? 
@CosmasZachos

Comment: So you got a classical limit for the Thirring model?

Comment: The way to take the classical question itself can be debated perhaps. But let's say since the duality is based on the coupling strengths then I'm gonna set $\hbar$ to $0$ and then see how the couplings are related. Well, I'd say the green functions should be matched to the zeorth order with respect to $\hbar$ too. @CosmasZachos

Comment: A good handle should be T-duality between 2d scalar theories. There, the geometrical and topological features of ***canonical transformation*** duality are easy to explore at the classical level, and carry over to quantization, so, indeed, quantization is irrelevant! Try [this talk](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9407044) and [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(96)00138-1)  and papers referring to them... The simplest one is [this one](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.52.R573).

Comment: @CosmasZachos But the question is the opposite way around. From the full theory to the classical limit. Let's specifically talk about AdS/SCFT as an example.

Comment: No, I'm giving you the simplest possible example, so you won't get sidetracked in irrelevancies. Simple 2d scalar field theories. The quantum DSM and CM are dual to each other and canonically equivalent, both quantum and classically: start from quantum, and the classical limits  are also dually related, with ***explicit nonlocal canonical transformations*** ! You cannot possibly get lost, unless you seek that: The examples that you believe will help you will actually confuse you, and you'll conclude that, "oh, it's really subtle; there is no end to it".. **Duality is not a quantum phenomenon**

Comment: https://www.ias.edu/sites/default/files/sns/duality(3).pdf
@CosmasZachos
What do you think?

Comment: The author recalls Montonen-Olive duality is already apparent in the classical limit, just as I reassured you is the case for T-duality! I assume you are not interested in fathoming in Ed's competing dualities: "such dualities are symmetries that exist only in the quantum world".